# Is there a better way to conditionally push to an array?

Tags: javascript

I have some data that I'm getting back from an API, and I have an empty array that I want to add some objects into. I want to check against the API data and if something exists in there, add something to this empty array.

So far, I have something like this

```
const data = [
  {id: 1, status: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED'},
  {id: 2, status: 'NEEDS_BILLING'},
  {id: 3, status: 'NEEDS_CODING'},
  {id: 4, status: 'NEEDS_INVOICING'},
];
```

and with this data I'm doing something like this:

```
const keys = []

if (data.some((appointment): boolean => appointment.billing_status === 'NO ACTION NEEDED')) {
  keys.push({ label: 'No Action Needed', value: 'NO ACTION NEEDED', color: 'red' })
}

if (data.some((appointment): boolean => appointment.billing_status === 'NEEDS_CODING')) {
  keys.push({ label: 'Needs Coding', value: 'NEEDS_CODING', color: 'yellow' })
}

// .... etc ....
```

and the expected value is something like this:

```
const keys = [
  { label: 'No Action Needed', value: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED', color: 'red' },
  { label: 'Needs Coding', value: 'NEEDS_CODING', color: 'yellow' },
  { label: 'Needs Invoicing', value: 'NEEDS_INVOICING', color: 'blue' },
  // .... etc
]
```

Is there an easier way to write something like this whether it's a method or abstracting it out into a function somehow? In my opinion it's not very DRY.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Set of the `billing_status`es in the `data` first, then iterate over an array of the labels and their colors to push:

```
const billingStatuses = new Set(data.map(obj => obj.billing_status));
const possibleLabels = [['No Action Needed', 'red'], ['Needs Coding', 'yellow'] /* ... */];
for (const [label, color] of possibleLabels) {
  const value = label.toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, '_');
  if (billingStatuses.has(value)) {
    keys.push({ label, value, color });
  }
}
```

Could also make an object instead of an array:

```
const possibleLabels = {
  'No Action Needed': 'red',
  'Needs Coding': 'yellow',
  // ...
};
for (const [label, color] of Object.entries(possibleLabels)) {
  // ...
```

Live demo:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, billing_status : 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED'},
  {id: 999, billing_status : 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED'},
  {id: 2, billing_status : 'NEEDS_BILLING'},
  {id: 3, billing_status : 'NEEDS_CODING'},
  {id: 4, billing_status : 'NEEDS_INVOICING'},
];
const possibleLabels = {
  'No Action Needed': 'red',
  'Needs Coding': 'yellow',
  // ...
};
const billingStatuses = new Set(data.map(obj => obj.billing_status));
const keys = [];
for (const [label, color] of Object.entries(possibleLabels)) {
  const value = label.toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, '_');
  if (billingStatuses.has(value)) {
    keys.push({ label, value, color });
  }
}
console.log(keys);
```

You can use an array for the `billingStatuses` instead of a Set, but `Set#has` is less computationally complex and is more appropriate for an unordered collection.

As a side note, keep in mind that there's rarely any need to explicitly note the return type of a function in Typescript - the compiler can very often figure that out on its own. (eg:

```
if (data.some((appointment): boolean => appointment.billing_status === 'NO ACTION NEEDED')) {
```

could have been replaced with

```
if (data.some((appointment) => appointment.billing_status === 'NO ACTION NEEDED')) {
```

to be more concise and allow less code surface area for bugs)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could be an alternative,

```
const dic = {};
for (const d of data) {
    if (!dic.hasOwnProperty(d.status)) {
        let label, value, color;
        switch(d.status) {
            case 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED':
                label = 'No action needed';
                value = 'NO ACTION NEEDED';
                color = 'red';
                break;
            // other cases ...
            default:
            // in case you have a default value
                label = 'Default';
                value = 'Default';
                color = 'black';
        }
        dic[d.status] = {label, value, color};
    }
}
const keys = Object.values(dic);
```

Simple, and you only iterate data once.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the easiest way with `map`.

### With duplicates

Example:

```js
const keys = data.map((appointment) => {
  switch(appointment.billing_status) {
    case 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED':
     return { label: 'No Action Needed', value: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED', color: 'red' };

    case 'NEEDS_CODING':
     return { label: 'Needs Coding', value: 'NEEDS_CODING', color: 'yellow' };

    // as many cases as you want

    default:
      return false;
  }
}).filter(item => Boolean);
```

Or you can do something like this.

```js
const actions = {
  NO_ACTION_NEEDED: { label: 'No Action Needed', color: 'red' },
  NEEDS_CODING: { label: 'Needs Coding', color: 'yellow' },
};

const keys = data.map((apointment) => {
  const action = actions[apointment.billing_status];
  if (!action) {
    return false;
  }

  return {
    title: action.title,
    value: apointment.billing_status,
    color: action.color,
  };
}).filter(item => Boolean);
```

`.filter(item => Boolean);` is used to remove false (elements with not allowed billing_status) elements from array.

### With no duplicates:

```js
// Predefined data
const data = [
  {id: 1, status: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED'},
  {id: 2, status: 'NEEDS_BILLING'},
  {id: 3, status: 'NEEDS_CODING'},
  {id: 4, status: 'NEEDS_INVOICING'},
  {id: 5, status: 'NEEDS_CODING'},
  {id: 6, status: 'NEEDS_BILLING'},
  {id: 7, status: 'NEEDS_INVOICING'},
];

// Generation settings
const statusDataMap = {
  NO_ACTION_NEEDED: { title: 'No Action Needed', color: 'red', value: 'NO_ACTION_NEEDED' },
  NEEDS_BILLING: { title: 'Needs billing', color: 'yellow', value: 'NEEDS_BILLING' },
  NEEDS_INVOICING: { title: 'Needs invoising', color: 'blue', value: 'NEEDS_INVOICING' },
};


// Working code

const statuses = [];
data.forEach((apointment) => {
  if (statuses.includes(apointment.status)) {
    return;
  }

  statuses.push(apointment.status);
});

const keys = statuses.map(status => statusDataMap[status]).filter(Boolean);


// Result
console.log(keys);
```